# Как установить всплывающее изображение(при наведении на текст мыши) всегда там,где находится курсор?

Tags: css

У меня картинка всплывает,но сверху страницы,а не там ,где курсор.Заранее спасибо за ответ.Пожалуйста,если можно,то с конкретными примерами,так как это мои первые шаги в освоении программирования)

Comment: выложи код, покажи, как ты делала и что у тебя не получилось.  так тебе быстрее помогут и подробнее опиши чего хочешь добиться...

Comment: судя по описанию одним css тут не обойтись. А так да, нужно больше информации: вводные данные, что пробовали, что получилось, желаемый результат.

Answer (score -2):

Лучше это сделать на js. Однако можно и на css, с определенными ограничениями. Можно заменить курсор вашей графикой через css-свойство `cursor: url()`. При этом в графику нужно добавить изображение курсора. Это может вызвать негативный пользовательский опыт, если курсор у пользователя отличается по внешнему виду от того что вы добавили себе в картинку.